# How can i pull only Hour Number with AM/PM in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

My Input :

```
2020-01-01 09:01:00.000
2020-01-03 18:01:00.000
```

My Output Should be like :

```
9 AM
6 PM
```

Comment: What is that input? A `datetime` or `datetime2` value?

Comment: I Want the Hour Number

Comment: that's obvious in the question. What is the *input* though? If it's a date-related type, you don't need the `CAST( as datetime)` or `CAST( as TIME)` expressions in most of the answers

Comment: If you want "the hour number", try `DATEPART( hour, time_field)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is a date-related type, you can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with the appropriate format string, eg :

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'HH:mm tt')
```

For me, this returns :

```
12:51 PM
```

Just `HH tt` returns the desired string, in this case :

```
12 PM
```

Comment: Its working fine  in ssms but FORMAT function is not recognised in SSRS :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the format function like this as long as you're using SQL Server 2012 or later.

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'h tt') AS MyTime
```

Note the use of the lower case 'h' which gives a 12 hour clock with no leading zero, 'HH' gives a two digit 24 hour clock so you end up with output like '16 PM'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conversion :

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(TIME, '2020-01-01 09:01:00.000'), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query.

```
SELECT convert(VARCHAR(30), cast('2020-01-01 09:01:00.000' AS DATETIME), 100)
    ,convert(VARCHAR(30), cast('2020-01-03 18:01:00.000' AS DATETIME), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
SELECT V.YourColumn,
       LTRIM(SUBSTRING(ca.v,13,2) + ' ' RIGHT(ca.v,2))
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(Datetime2(3),'2020-01-01 09:01:00.000')),
            (CONVERT(Datetime2(3),'2020-01-03 18:01:00.000')))V(YourColumn)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(varchar(30),V.YourColumn,0))) ca(v);
```

In the `CROSS APPLY` I convert the datetime to the format `MMM d YYYY h:mmAM/PM`, then you can use `SUBSTRING`/`LEFT` to get the bits you want.

An alternative approach would be to use `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CASE DATEPART(HOUR,V.YourColumn) WHEN 12 THEN 12 WHEN 0 THEN 12 ELSE DATEPART(HOUR,V.YourColumn) % 12 END,' ', RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(30),V.YourColumn,0),2))
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(Datetime2(3),'2020-01-01 09:01:00.000')),
            (CONVERT(Datetime2(3),'2020-01-03 00:01:00.000')),
            (CONVERT(Datetime2(3),'2020-01-03 18:01:00.000')))V(YourColumn);
```

Because `12 % 12` and `0 % 12` both = `0`, then you need the `CASE` expression to handle those.